# Exp-resso store - do something on status change

Tags: expresso-store

I was just wondering if there is a way to create an extension that allows me to do something if an order's status is changed. There doesn't currently seem to be a hook that allows this to happen, but I'm sure there was in Store 1...

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't currently an extension hook which is called when an order status is changed (there wasn't in Store 1 either).

However, it's a pretty obvious requirement so I'll make sure it is included in the next version (coming shortly after EE 2.8).

Update: `store_order_update_status_start` and `store_order_update_status_end` hooks are included in Store 2.3.0:

https://exp-resso.com/docs/extension_hooks.html#order_status_hooks

Comment: We want ALL the hooks, Adrian!

Comment: That's right, hook us up!